# Parsing KML file with java api for kml

Tags: java, parsing, kml

I am attempting to parse a KML file which has some non-standard tags:

```
<Placemark id="plot">
<Type1> Type 1 </Type1>
<SA>62</SA>
<Type2> Type 2 </Type2>
```

I'm attempting to read/parse the file, obtain the representative elements as described above and then all the coordinates, and finally write the output to a text file for downstream use.  I'm able to parse the file and get the coordinates with no issues but have been unable to determine a way to get the custom elements,  and I need the data to format the output file correctly.  The elements are not wrapped in an extendeddata structure or any other grouping.

I am hoping someone has run into this before and can offer some guidance on the best way to read the data via supplied methods for javaapiforkml.

Comment: How are you parsing kml data?

Comment: the snippet you have included is not xml. Can you post a better snippet?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, it's a KML file.  The section I included is a placemark tag.  There are hundreds in the KML file.  I was just trying to highlight the custom fields and how they are represented in the file.

Comment: I'm using the "javaapiforkml" plug-in, which unmarshalls the KML file to Java objects and provides methods for accessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at OSMBonusPack KML parser, mainly [here](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/source/browse/trunk/OSMBonusPack/src/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/kml/KmlDocument.java).

It's open source, so you can pick the classes you need, remove all Android-specific features, and add handling for your custom tags.